# Rails rmagick - Converted Image Turns Solid Black When 'resize_to_fit' applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I have an image I am reading from a pdf file and converting to jpg.  It works fine, until I apply "resize_to_fit" - which results in a black-rectangle (of the specified size).

```
file = file + "[0]"
jpg_file = file + ".jpg"
pdf = Magick::Image.read(file) do
  self.quality = 80
  self.density = '300'
  self.colorspace = Magick::RGBColorspace
  self.interlace = Magick::NoInterlace
end
pdf.first.resize_to_fit!("600")
}
pdf.first.write(jpg_file)
```

Subsituting:

```
pdf.first.change_geometry!('600x600') { |cols, rows, img|
  img.resize!(cols, rows)
}
```

... for the resize makes no difference, nor changing the quality, or the density, nor omitting the colorspace and interlace settings.

Since I have a good image at full size (a mostly white image), I don't see why "resize" or "change_geometry" would output pure black.

Ideas?

---

Dozens of random experiments later, I found the only conversion of size which does not output a black rectangle, is:

```
pdf.first.sample!(0.25)
```

The limitation, of course, is that I must have a consistent input-size for this to work, as the other argument-set (x and y) will change the aspect-ratio.

Also, the quality produced by 'sample' is horrible, no matter the settings applied on the input or output side.

I need a way to get resize_to_fit to work properly. I am following the docs and examples, so the result makes no sense.  I really hope someone who uses rmagick often, and is familiar with what parts of it are not broken, or what I am doing wrong, can respond with help.  Thanks

---

Answer from @bumpy was the solution.  I am now doing it a different way using Carrierwave, but I rewound the code and did an A:B test; the line

```
pdf.first.alpha(Magick::DeactivateAlphaChannel)
```

... works.  Note that Carrierwave does the conversion correctly, and with decent quality results (identical to this solution), without any special settings.  I would guess this is built into its defaults for conversions to jpg.

Comment: Can I have a link to the PDF you're using?

Comment: Here is one I've tried:  http://www.jorns.ch/upload/occasionen/1/190/reference1.pdf

Comment: Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible your PDF file has a transparent background, which is causing the problem. Try removing the alpha channel before the resize using

```
pdf.first.alpha(Magick::DeactivateAlphaChannel)
pdf.first.resize_to_fit!("600")
```